# Checking which object called the other's object method

Tags: c++, oop, methods

Let's say I have two classes:

```
class TV
{
   ...
   void TV_chnl_change(int channel_number);
   ...
};

class Remote
{
   ...

   void remote_chnl_change(int channel_number, TV *T)
   {
      T->TV_chnl_change(channel_number);
   }

   ...
};
```

Both showed methods are public, what I want to do is to implement `TV_chnl_change` method such that it can check whether it was called by object from `Remote` class. Is there any way in cpp to obtain the pointer to the calling object or at least check its class without passing any additional parameters?
I don't want any object other than `Remote` and let's say some arbitrary `Viewer` object to be able to use `TV_chnl_change` method. What I want to do is to omit using friend mechanism.

Comment: Short answer: No.  The function knows nothing about it's call site, unless you pass that information to the function.

Comment: Store an identifier (probably an enum) in the remote class and pass it to the TV_chnl_change() function.

Comment: That information will be on the call stack.  You can do a [backtrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) in linux.  The amount of information available in the backtrace in release mode will depend heavily on the optimizations that were performed.

Comment: Inherit TV from ISecretTVFunctionality and then pass an ISecretTVFunctionality* only to those objects that you want to have access to the secret functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have a public method which you need to restrict access to? You should assign it as private and write an interface for it.